# Why does the second call to my function get triggered twice? (Swift iOS timer/speechrecognition)

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, speech, speech-synthesis

`self.adaResponseApi` runs twice when the timer hits 1.5 seconds after the last recorded speech input. It should only run once.

It is specifically running from the 1.5 interval instantiation and not from the first instantiation, which is triggered when the user specifically-stops speech input.

```
recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
    if result != nil {
        self.textView.text = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString
        self.isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!
    }

    if let timer = self.detectionTimer, (timer.isValid) {
        if self.isFinal! {
            self.detectionTimer?.invalidate()
            self.adaResponseApi()
            self.isFinal = true
        }
    } else  { // if self.isFinal == false
        self.detectionTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.5, repeats: false, block: { timer in
            self.adaResponseApi() // This call gets triggered twice and for the life of me I can't figure out why.
            timer.invalidate()
            self.isFinal = true
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: self.adaResponseApi runs twice when the timer hits 1.5 seconds after the last recorded speech input. It should only run once. It is specifically running from the 1.5 interval instantiation and not from the first instantiation, which is triggered when the user specifically-stops speech input.

Comment: Put that in the question. Using the edit button :)

Comment: isn't it is written twice, once when the timer is valid and another when timer is invalidated?
Check if speechRecognizer.recognitionTask block is called twice.

Comment: What library are you using for the speech recognition? What type is `speechRecognizer`?

Comment: let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: "en-GB"))!

Comment: Are you wanting to cancel the task if it takes longer than 1.5 seconds?

Comment: It's a speech-to-text to watson ibm text-to-speech process. I'm using the native speech to to text and text to speech. I'm trying to make it so that when the micriphone is pressed 'off', it submits the api call. also when the timer hits 1.5 duration seconds since the last word in the speech recognition engine, it submits the api call.

Comment: Please can you show how you are creating the `recognitionRequest`. Just want to get all the parts together before I answer :D Thanks

Comment: I added an answer. I hope that helps with what you are doing. Let me know if I got any assumptions wrong and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK here goes... I'm assuming that the request has `shouldReportPartialResults` set to `true` (default value).

```
recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { [weak self] (result, error) in
    // [weak self] to stop memory leaks

    guard let result = result else {
        // no result means probably an error, you should report that to your user
        return
    }

    // display the most accurate transcription (partial or final)
    self?.textView.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString

    // invalidate timer
    // result is final (and so should invalidate timer)
    // or result is partial (and so will create new timer ... and invalidate this one)
    self?.detectionTimer?.invalidate()

    if result.isFinal {
        // we have a final result... use it
        self?.adaResponseApi()
    } else {
        // create timer for if the next response times out
        self?.detectionTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.5, repeats: false) { [weak self] timer in
            self?.adaResponseApi()
        }
    }
}
```

I think I would do it something like this...

I'm not 100% certain what your timer is there for so I assumed it's there in case the recogniser does not return a response quickly and so we can fall back to the most recent `partial` result?

I also don't think we should need to store the value of `result.isFinal`. If you do need that then you can add it to the line after `self?.textView.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString`.

Comment: This worked beautifully. The timer wasn't incase it timed out but to automatically submit the query after 1.5 seconds of silence. But it worked exactly as intended. Thank you so much

Comment: There's one problem with this though. When I cancel the recording without any input the speechrecognizer task segfaults the app

Comment: No idea, it just outputs this then the app hangs: 2018-04-11 09:28:17.488811+0100 Ada[4083:907046] [Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=203 "Retry" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Retry, NSUnderlyingError=0x1d4450590 {Error Domain=SiriSpeechErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"}}

Comment: @VortexRingState looks like it’s the Ada stuff “Ada[4083:...” take a look there. Also... you might have to cancel the timer as well as cancelling the request. If the timer has been created then there are two possible ways to call the Ada stuff.

Comment: No sorry. It's definitely the speech engine crashing. Ada is the name of the project, hence the reference. I will work on it. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: @VortexRingState add an exception breakpoint. I can’t help without any more context. Add a new question for that though.